# JQuery issue with a back to top function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a Back to Top function with jQuery.

The scroll back to top works but I can't seem to figure out how to hide it and only appear when say `scrollTop() > 300`. I created a function to take care of that but unfortunately no luck.

Here's a link to a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pvan_ren1/st3mdp6a/10/

```
//This is the function that's supposed to take care of the hide and reveal of toTop button.
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
        btn.addClass('show');
    } else {
        btn.removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I can't see any CSS for the class `show` in your demo? The javascript you've written is working fine though. Also, I think users trying to help would appreciate a slightly less 'demanding' message in your HTML.

Comment: So did you set it to be hidden by default? I am guessing no.

Comment: I'd also put that `<a id="toTop"></a>` inside of the body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit your CSS to hide your "Back to Top" button by default, and then show it when the `show` class is added.

```css
#toTop {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FF9800;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#toTop.show {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = $('#toTop');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            btn.addClass('show');
        } else {
            btn.removeClass('show');
        }
    });

    btn.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
    });
});
```

```css
.sectionA {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.sectionB {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: green;
}

.sectionC {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.sectionD {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#toTop {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FF9800;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#toTop.show {
    display: inline-block;
}
#toTop:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333;
}
#toTop:active {
    background-color: #555;
}
#toTop::after {
    content: "\f077";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p style="position:fixed">Scroll Down and use the toTop button</p>
<br>
<p style="position:fixed">
At the top, the "Back to Top" button does not show.
<b>It works!</b>
</p>
<section class="sectionA">

</section>
<section class="sectionB">

</section>
<section class="sectionC">

</section>
<section class="sectionD">

</section>
</body>
<a id="toTop"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, set the style of the button to `display: none` then the code below should do it for you:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
           $('#toTop').css('display','inline-block');
        } else {
             $('#toTop').css('display','none');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cool thanks, tweaking the display works. What a dumb-dumb.